# Target DE for inserting data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpagesurl

When using InsertData() to add a row to a DE such as the example below:

```
InsertData("TestDE", "EmailAddress", @EmailAddress)
```

How does it know where "TestDE" is? If there is a folder path to get to TestDE does it need to be defined so that the target DE is clear?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to provide the folder path. Just reference the Data Extension by name. Data Extension names are unique across the Business Unit [MID].

[What is the difference between the Name and the CustomerKey of a data extension?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362897/what-is-the-difference-between-the-name-and-the-customerkey-of-a-data-extension)